# Perform INSERT in Stored Procedure after SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query a list of users from one table:

```
SELECT username FROM Users WHERE birthday = todaysDate
```

And use the returned results to insert into another table

```
INSERT INTO Message (username, message) VALUES (*username from query above*, 'Happy Birthday')
```

I can query the results and I can insert into tables with hard-coded values, but I'm not sure how to approach looping through results in SQL and performing action as I have only done that in VBScript using a recordset.

Will I need to make 2 separate stored procedures for this? Or is a stored procedure not even the right route to take here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in one call:

```
INSERT INTO Message (username, message)
SELECT username, 'Happy Birthday'
FROM Users
WHERE birthday = todaysDate
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I don't have a lot of experience with SQL. Didn't know a simple SELECT could include a string parameter that wasn't part of the destination table. I thought I was going to have to use an EXISTS or something. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO Message (username, message) 
    SELECT username, 'Happy Birthday'
    FROM Users
    WHERE birthday = todaysDate;
```